# What does the "First rollback" description mean for the badge Cleanup

Tags: support, badges

I do not understand what the description "First Rollback" means for the badge Cleanup. What is a rollback? Can someone please explain to me what this is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rollback is when you undo an edit, see here:

- [What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback)